# Access managed JSF beans in authorize tag of Spring security

Tags: spring, security, jsf, el, authorize

I implemented Spring security 4.2.3. in an JSF-2.2 web application and it works fine so far. Now I have a problem in accessing a jsf bean methode from the authorize tag of spring security.

This is my xhtml data table where i need to deny access in some rows according to item data:

```
<p:dataTable var="item" value="#{itemService.items}">
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Name">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Security">
        <sec:authorize access="#{securityService.checkAccessByItemId(item.id)}">
            <h:outputLabel value="#{helloWorld.secure}"/>
        </sec:authorize>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

And here my bean just for testing:

```
@ManagedBean(name="securityService")
@RequestScoped
public class SecurityService {

    public boolean checkAccessByItemId(int id) {
        if(id==5) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here my taglib.xml:

```
<facelet-taglib>
   <namespace>http://www.springframework.org/security/tags</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>authorize</tag-name>
        <handler class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler</handler-class>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

I am getting this exception:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [#{securityService.checkAccessByItemId(item.id)}] @1: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.raiseInternalException(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:1006)
```

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Did you check if the Spring EL supports parameterized method calls?

Comment: Same error comes when i call methods without parameters

Comment: Now I read the error correctly (and checked the Spring Security docs!!!) are you sure you can use EL in them? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/taglibs.html#taglibs-authorize

Answer (score 0):

If I read the [Spring-Security documentation for the authorize tag](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/taglibs.html#taglibs-authorize) correctly, it does not seem EL in there is supported (why would you use the authorize tag anyway if you want to call your own bean to 'validate' things? Just use the `rendered` attribute on the outputLabel then.

Comment: Yes, the rendered attribute would be a solution in this simple example. I only wanted to know if there is a way to controll access or the nessesary authorities dynamicly by using manged beans. But it seems like this is not supported.